# Where can I ask a question about random choice?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have written a program which should generate random numbers.

> Basic implementation:
>
> Capture current time >> wait 0.00001 seconds >> capture time again and subtract both of them.
> Since the computers (at least the one I have) has an accuracy of up to 84% at only 0.01 seconds, setting the interval of 0.00001 will make it inaccurate. I will then use the last digit of the difference returned.

My question is about how I can verify if this method renders a true random number? I ask because running a probability experiment returned some surprisingly different observations than what it should have.

I think this belongs to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) but at the same time it can go to [SciComp](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com), [CS](https://cs.stackexchange.com), [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your best bet here may be [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) (do note you need to include your code there).

They have other questions like yours, for example [this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/95768/160652) that asks the exact same question as you (does my implementation give a true random number) for an implementation in C++.

Comment: I think it's an exact duplicate, my code is in python and uses time module...Thanks for prompt response.

Comment: @QueenieGoldstein Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.SystemRandom

Comment: @PM2Ring I saw the link, it looks like this was discussed thoroughly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145510/random-is-barely-random-at-all)

Comment: @QueenieGoldstein No, there's no mention of SystemRandom on that page. It discusses Mersenne Twister (the usual PRNG that Python uses unless you specifically use SystemRandom), which is an excellent PRNG, but unlike SystemRandom it is *not* suitable for cryptographic use.

Comment: Sorry for going off-topic, Tinks, I just didn't want Queenie to use a suboptimal randomizer, in case this is for crypto stuff, because that can be dangerous.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for the information, I was also heading for a cryptography course. System.random is entropy but time capture at ridiculuosly high precision is entropy as well. I will look for/ask more on Code review. :)

Comment: Funnily, it looks like the normal random module (with a little bit variation) :P (A PRNG after running a probability experiment). Also, sorry Tinks for the pings